# used EggJS: After deployment, the access interface always reports an error of 502 bad gateway

Tags: node.js, nginx, egg

### What happens?

The project can be deployed successfully without any error, but when I request the interface, nginx will feed back the error

```
upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 171.221.xxx.xxx, server: api.example.club, request: "GET /api/webInfo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:7111/api/webInfo", host: "api.example.club"
```

Then I tried to change the configuration, but it still didn't take effect: the configuration is as follows

#### config.default.ts

```
config.proxy = true;

config.httpclient = {
    request: {
        timeout: 50000,
    },
    httpAgent: {
        freeSocketTimeout: 40000,
    },
    httpsAgent: {
        freeSocketTimeout: 40000,
    },
};
```

#### app.ts

```
import { Application, IBoot } from 'egg';

export default class FooBoot implements IBoot {
  private readonly app: Application;

  constructor(app: Application) {
    this.app = app;
  }

  async serverDidReady() {
    this.app.server.timeout = 0
    this.app.server.keepAliveTimeout = 0
  }

}
```

#### Nginx config

```
server
{
    listen 80;
    server_name api.example.club;
    index index.html index.htm default.htm default.html;
    #root /www/wwwroot/blog-server;
    
    #SSL-START
    #error_page 404/404.html;
    
    #SSL-END
    
    #ERROR-PAGE-START
    #error_page 404 /404.html;
    #error_page 502 /502.html;
    #ERROR-PAGE-END
    
    
    #REWRITE-START
    include /www/server/panel/vhost/rewrite/node_server.conf;
    #REWRITE-END
    
    location ~ ^/(\.user.ini|\.htaccess|\.git|\.svn|\.project|LICENSE|README.md|package.json|package-lock.json|\.env|node_modules) {
        return 404;
    }
    
    
    location /.well-known/ {
        root  /www/wwwroot/server;
    }

    
    location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        proxy_cache_purge cache_one $host$request_uri$is_args$args;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:7111;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
        add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;

        proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
        proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
        proxy_send_timeout 30s;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
   
    
    access_log  /www/wwwlogs/server.log;
    error_log  /www/wwwlogs/server.error.log;
}
```

### Mini Showcase Repository(REQUIRED)

#### Code address

https://github.com/Shen120/rp_egg

### How To Reproduce

**Steps to reproduce the behavior:**

1. Run after deployment
2. Then request the interface

**Expected behavior**
1.It can be accessed normally, and 502 no longer appears

### Context

- **Node Version**:14.17.1
- **Egg Version**:2.33.1
- **egg-bin**:4.16.4
- **egg-cors**:2.2.3
- **Platform**: liunx

Comment: Are you sure the app is running on port 7111, since that is what you have in the nginx conf ? On the github i see `open http://localhost:7001/` in the readme.

Comment: 7001 is only a local running port. After deployment, it runs on port 7111. Sorry, the readme file has not been updated

Answer (score 0):

I got it!Because my service is configured with HTTPS, but the address of the reverse proxy is HTTP, so 502